How to process big data in my case?
I have 54 data files generated by a simulation. Each file has 10 million rows, and each file is several GB in size.
I need to read each file, compute their autocorrelation, and fit the curve.
What is the best way to do that in the shortest time possible?
I am using the C# programming language, parallel loops, and stream readers. To give you an idea, reading and processing 2 million lines from nine different files (i.e., 18 million lines in total) is taking 4 hours.
This is the configuration of the remote computer I am working on:
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                12
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-11
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    6
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 45
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 0 @ 2.30GHz
Stepping:              7
CPU MHz:               2625.762
CPU max MHz:           2800,0000
CPU min MHz:           1200,0000
BogoMIPS:              4600.17
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              15360K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-11

Should I migrate to Amazon AWS or should I rent HPC clusters?

Judging from the question, I suppose the problem is both about hardware and software: you need some high throughput computation power (probably distributed or cloud) to do the math within a reasonable time-frame, and a software of which hardware can accept the job.
I am not familiar with C#, but recommend to first do some research on what cloud/cluster solutions are available for C#. Given that you already have some level of parallelization in your code, if you can find a suitable solution then just run your code on this service (be it a super-computer or cluster) and job done.
The first thing that comes to my mind is Spark, which is a standard computation service available on most cloud platforms (AWS/GCP etc.). Good news is Spark supports C# so check if it can do your job and for any necessary code adaption. Otherwise, if Spark cannot do it then look for other feasible solutions/platforms that C# can work on.
In worst case, you may have to find another framework that can do your job and rewrite your code as another programming language. Let's leave this as the last resort.
By the way, in general for cloud services the more you pay, the faster you get the result. Watch your budget and urgency wisely.
